# How can I change the buttons OR function of available buttons on a jQuery dialog window after it has been loaded?

Tags: javascript

So I am opening a

```
$('#someelement').dialog({ title.......
                           autoOpen: false,
                           //......

                           buttons: { OK: function() {
                                   $(this).dialog('close');}
                           },
                           //....
                         });
```

During this time a timer is running, if the user clicks "OK" I don't want anything to occur, but if the timer has run down, I would like change the function.  I have tried the following unsuccessfully:

```
jQuery('#SessionTimeoutWarningDialog').dialog('option', 'buttons', {
                    'OK': function() {
                        RedirectToLogin;
                        jQuery(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                });
```

What am I doing wrong, or how should I be handling this?

Comment: what is RedirectToLogin? Is this a method - if so, use RedirectToLogin();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I'll answer my own:

```
//........
$('#someelement').dialog('option', 'buttons', {
     'buttonName': function() {
          //your new functionality;
      }
 });
```

or with the beforeClose event:

```
$('#someelement').bind('dialogbeforeclose', function() {
      //your new functionality;
});
```